# filters stopped working ..shows blank page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When I click my headers, it does not sort and the table disappears

```
angular.module('maniaApp')
  .controller('EventCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$http) {


    $scope.sortType     = '_source.event_name'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchEvent   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

    var url = "http://api.loc/events/get-events";

    $http.get(url).success(function api(data, status, headers, config){
      $scope.events = data;
    }).error(function api(data, status, headers, config){
      console.error(data, status, headers, config);
    });
```

here is my html

```
<div class="container">
  <!--<div ng-view=""></div>-->
  <div ng-controller="EventCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>Sort Type: {{ sortType }}</p>
      <p>Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}</p>
      <p>Search Query: {{ searchEvent }}</p>
    </div>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search events" ng-model="searchEvent">

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = '_source.id'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Id
            <span ng-show="sortType == '_source.id';" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = '_source.event_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            <span ng-show="sortType == '_source.event_name';" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            Event Name
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = '_source.event_status_id'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            <span ng-show="sortType == '_source.event_sid'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            Event Status
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchEvent">
        <td>{{ event._source.event_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ event._source.event_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ event._source.event_sid }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What data your http service returns? I make a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GQoUBYCmHzeZBNyWJVO3?p=preview) with your example and all works fine (except you sort by `_source.id`, but show `_source.event_id`, but this is irrelevant anyway).

Comment: thank you. I think it was redirecting to wrong place in the href #. I did #/events and it started working. Sorry I should have added app.js in this as well.